# ionic mobile app working fine on development but not in production

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing my first ionic app. I have finished it and it works perfectly when i make

```
ionic serve --open
```

Or when I open it on the Ionic DevApp on my mobile device.

When I create the .apk, almost every functionality works fine; but this one not:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [enabled]="  _tabs.textToEnableTabs !='AddListPage' " tabTitle="Pending Tasks" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [enabled]="  _tabs.textToEnableTabs !='AddListPage' " tabTitle="Finished Tasks" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" [enabled]="  _tabs.textToEnableTabs !='AddListPage' " tabTitle="Contact Author" tabIcon="contacts">      </ion-tab>
```

This code checks if we are on certain component or not, so in case we are on that component, we make tabs not to be clickable.

As I said, this functionality works perfectly on development but not on production, where tabs are ALWAYS clickable. So the `[enabled]` tag or the condition is not working fine. I don´t know.

Which could be the problem?

In case it helps you, I have a service ShowTabsService where I create that property

```
//ShowTabsService.ts

textToEnableTabs
```

And I initialize on constructor:

```
"ShowTabsService.ts constructor

constructor()
{
    this.textToEnableTabs=""; /*value will change on the addList.ts constructor and on its onDestroy, to make tabs available again*/
}
```

When I am on the constructor of the AddListPage, where tabs should not be clickeable, I do:

```
//AddListPage.ts

constructor(
    private _viewController:ViewController,
    private _tabs:ShowTabsService) {

       this._tabs.textToEnableTabs=this._viewController.name; //this will be 'AddListPage' when we are on that component

}
```

And on the ngOnInit, when we leave that component, we make tabs clickable again by doing:

```
//AddListPage.ts

ngOnDestroy()
{
    this._tabs.textToEnableTabs="";
}
```

Maybe it is not the best way of doing it (I am new on both Angular and Ionic) but as I said, that works right on development. Not when I install the signed APK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested me the solution [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-mobile-app-working-fine-on-development-but-not-in-production/144733/3)

The problem was, on this part of the code:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [enabled]="  _tabs.textToEnableTabs !='AddListPage' " tabTitle="Pending Tasks" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
```

I was relying on class names, and those will be minified when you build your app in production, that´s why my code was working fine on development mode but not in production.

I suggest to read [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-current-page-name/52993/19) on the ionic forum